# Simplifying many-indents-code

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following code, written in Python:

```
if id:
    fields = r.table(cls._tablename)
              .get(id)
              .run(cls.connection())
else:
    try:
        fields = list(r.table(cls._tablename)
                       .filter(**kwargs)
                       .limit(1)
                       .run(cls.connection()))[0]
    except IndexError:
        fields = None
```

The code acts as a wrapper for getting a document from a RethinkDB datastore. I find all those indents unaesthetic, and I cannot seem to find a way to wrap the lines to look nicer.

So, is there a way I can rewrite (or maybe just rewrap) this code to look better and provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like

```
table = r.table(cls._tablename)

if id:
    fields = table.get(id).run(cls.connection())

else:        
    filtered = table.filter(**kwargs).limit(1)
    fieldss = filtered.run(cls.connection()) 

    # Consider "next(iter(fieldss), None)"
    try:
        fields = list(fieldss)[0]        
    except IndexError:
        fields = None
```

where I replace `tableid`, `table`, `filtered` and `fieldss` with *descriptive* names (rather than my generic stand-ins).

I find that typically there's no reason to try and be too clever with the workflow. It's easier to have logically discrete steps; a chain might look pretty but it's harder to comment, format, move and reason about. For example, the `next` tip in the code was only obvious once I split up the lines.

Comment: You are right, I tended to put everything in one command, but it looks prettier if I split everything into smaller, readable parts. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your indentations strike me as reasonable.  In any case, in functions you can often use return statements to help avoid indentation ...

```
def get_fields(id):
    if id:
        fields = ...
        return fields

    try:
        fields = ...
    except:
        fields = ...

    return fields
```

Answer (score 2):

PEP8 allows for violations when it makes sense (and it does in this case. For instance, you can try something like this:

```
if id:
    fields = r.table(cls._tablename).get(id).run(cls.connection())
else:
    try:
        fields = list(
            r.table(cls._tablename)
                .filter(**kwargs)
                .limit(1)
                .run(cls.connection())
        )[0]
    except IndexError:
        fields = None
```

Or this:

```
if id:
    fields = r.table(cls._tablename)
        .get(id)
        .run(cls.connection())
else:
    try:
        fields = list(r.table(cls._tablename)
            .filter(**kwargs)
            .limit(1)
            .run(cls.connection()))[0]
    except IndexError:
        fields = None
```

Whatever you think looks best in your situation, even if it violates PEP8.

Answer (score 1):

Not really much you can do about the aesthetics of Python's indent style. Perhaps you can do as such:

```
if id:
    fields = r.table(cls._tablename).get(id).run(cls.connection())
else:
    try:
        fields = list(r.table(cls._tablename).filter(**kwargs).limit(1).run(cls.connection()))[0]
    except IndexError:
        fields = None
```

of maybe break the line with a backslash ():

```
if id:
    fields = r.table(cls._tablename).get(id).run(cls.connection())
else:
    try:
        fields = \
            list(r.table(cls._tablename).filter(**kwargs).limit(1).run(cls.connection()))[0]
    except IndexError:
        fields = None
```

Comment: The lines become too long this way and don't comply to PEP8 anymore.

Comment: Hmm, good point